# vector return type for function in C++ throwing error

Tags: c++

I built a simple `split` function in C++ which will split a string using delimiters. I put the function in GP.cpp and declared the function in GP.h.

GP.cpp:

```
#include "GP.h"

#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

vector<string> GP::split(string text, string delimiter) {
    vector<string> result;
    size_t pos;
    string token;
    while( (pos = text.find(delimiter)) != string::npos ) {
        token = text.substr(0, pos);
        result.push_back(token);
        text.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
    }
    return result;
}
```

GP.h:

```
#ifndef GP
#define GP

#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class GP {

    public:
        static vector<string> split(string text, string delimiter);

};

#endif
```

My editor will comment at `vector<string>` of the cpp file the following:
`explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)`

And when I try to build, I get this error:
`'split': is not a member of 'std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>>'`

Comment: Just an aside, "using namespace" in headers is very bad form and can lead to many problems.  And in general, you should avoid "using namespace std".  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice/

Comment: Instead of deleting the contents of your source string you can just begin the search at the place after the previous find: `for(pos = 0; text.find(delimiter, pos) != std::string::npos; pos += delimiter.length()) { ... }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#define GP` means that the token `GP` in the program will be replaced by blank. So this transforms the code:

```
class GP {
```

into

```
class {
```

and other such cases leading to your errors.

To fix this, make your include guards use tokens that are less likely to collide with other tokens in your program.

Also it is considered bad practice to put `using namespace std;` in the header, since anybody else using your header cannot undo it. It would be better to use `std::` qualification in the header instead.

Comment: Better yet, stop using obsolete include guards and switch to `#pragma once`.

Comment: @SergeyA `pragma once` is not in Standard C++

Comment: While this is true, I am not aware of any modern compiler which doesn't support it. In essence, I treat it as anything else which is not standard C++, yet impossible to not use, like Posix API, for example. Yes, non-standard. Yes, will use.

Comment: @SergeyA I don't use Posix API in most of my projects

Comment: But I am pretty sure your programs use something else which is not standard C++.    Posix, WinAPI, sockets, Boost...

Answer (score 3):

Exhibit one for not using `#ifdef` guards in modern C++ code. That's what `#pragma once` is for.

You're defining `GP` to be an empty string, so your header actually looks like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class  {

    public:
        static vector<string> split(string text, string delimiter);

};
```

I hope it's immediately obvious what the problem is now.

Comment: Hi, I'm not understanding what #pragma once is for. What does it replace?

Comment: Your `#ifndef`/`#define`/`#endif` statements

Comment: There are no standard pragmas.

Comment: Didn't say it was standard, it's just supported by every compiler that matters. If your every day usage of Turbo C++ doesn't support it, Neil, feel free to ignore my suggestion and use `#ifndef`!